# If option is selected do something in php

Tags: php

I have this code :

```
<html>

<head>    
</head>

<body>
    <select>    
        <?php 

            $colors = array("red", "green", "blue", "yellow"); 
            foreach ($colors as $value) {
                echo "<option>$value</option>";
            }

            if (in_array("blue",$value)) {
                echo "Blue is your color";         
            } else {
                echo "blue is not your color get out of here";
            }

        ?>
    </select>
</body>

</html>
```

Basically there is a variable which is an array containing different colors. 
I put that variable in a for loop inside a select, so people can select the options. I'm trying to achieve when people select the array attribute blue to echo something.

My attempt:

```
 if (in_array("blue",$value)) {
                echo "Blue is your color";         
            } else {
                echo "blue is not your color get out of here";
            }
```

I did some research before coming here, but found nothing or i didn't really know what to look for, but this is my attempt, I tried!

Comment: Outside the loop you are trying to catch a value of loop. What is actually you are going to do?? Are you going to show something on select the blue color?? If then you need to use jQuery / JavaScript.

Comment: You want to show some text based on selected option without reload the page, isn't it ?

Comment: why not javascript or jQuery, because in php you need to use form here you cant get the values on client side

Comment: Yes, exactly @AdrienLeber

Comment: So, you'll need to follow the @devpro's instruction and use jQuery Ajax.

Comment: @AdrienLeber: yes, u r right, for client side you can use jquery here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get values on client side than you can use jQuery or Javascript here, or if you want to use server side than you must need to use `<form>` here:

*Here is the basic example with jQuery you can modify as per your need, i am using result in alert box you can display it anywhere where you need:*

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<select name="select" id="select">    
<option value="">Select</option>
<?php 
$colors = array("red", "green", "blue", "yellow"); 
foreach ($colors as $value) {
?>
  <option value="<?=$value?>"><?=$value?></option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>
```

**jQuery:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#select").change(function(){
    selectVal = $(this).val();
    myarray = ["red", "green", "blue", "yellow"];
    if($.inArray(selectVal, myarray) !== -1){
      alert(selectVal+' is your color');
    }
    else{
      alert(selectVal+' is not your color get out of here');
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

*Make sure, you have included the jquery file in your code `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>`*

Answer (score 1):

You should write

```
 <html>

    <head>    
    </head>

    <body>
<?php 
$colors = array("red", "green", "blue", "yellow"); 
if(isset($_GET)&&$_GET["colors"]!=""){
if (in_array($_GET["colors"],$colors)) {
                    echo "$_GET["colors"] is your color";         
                } else {
                    echo "blue is not your color get out of here";
                }
 }
?>
<form method="get">
        <select name="colors">    
            <?php    

                foreach ($colors as $value) {
                    echo "<option value='".$value."'>$value</option>";
                }
            ?>
        </select>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
    </body>

    </html>
```

**in_array**

(PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7)
in_array — Checks if a value exists in an array

**Description**

bool in_array ( mixed $needle , array $haystack [, bool $strict = FALSE ] )
Searches haystack for needle using loose comparison unless strict is set.

**Parameters**

needle
The searched value.

Note:
If needle is a string, the comparison is done in a case-sensitive manner.
haystack
The array.

strict
If the third parameter strict is set to TRUE then the in_array() function will also check the types of the needle in the haystack.

**Return Values**

Returns TRUE if needle is found in the array, FALSE otherwise.

refer http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Answer (score 1):

if you use `javascript` to do that in easy way. before that you need to use `form` tag.  using `onchange="myfunction(this.value)"` method to get currect selected values form select box.

```
    <head>    
    <script>
    function myfunction(x)
    {
        alert(x);
    }
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <select id="myvalue" onchange="myfunction(this.value)">    
            <?php 

                $colors = array("red", "green", "blue", "yellow"); 
                foreach ($colors as $value) {
                    echo "<option>$value</option>";
                }

                if (in_array("blue",$value)) {
                    echo "Blue is your color";         
                } else {
                    echo "blue is not your color get out of here";
                }

            ?>
        </select>
        </form>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP doesn't handle user events. Use jQuery:

```
<body>
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"   integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<select id="select1">

    <?php 
    $colors = array("red", "green", "blue", "yellow"); 
    foreach ($colors as $value) {
        echo "<option value='$value'>$value</option>";
    }   
    ?>
</select>
<input type="text" id="selected">
<script>
    $('#select1').on('change', function() {
        $('#selected').val( this.value );
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need javascript or jquery to achieve what you want. Here is a pure javascript example:

**HTML**

```
<head>    
</head>

<body>
    <select onchange="checkColor(this);">    
        <?php 

            $colors = array("red", "green", "blue", "yellow"); 
            foreach ($colors as $value) {
                echo "<option>$value</option>";
            }
        ?>
    </select>
</body>

</html>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script>
function checkColor(selectObj){
if (selectObj.selectedIndex == -1){
        selectedColor = '';
}
else {
    selectedColor = selectObj.options[selectObj.selectedIndex].text;
}

if(selectedColor == 'blue'){
    alert('Blue is your color');
}
else {
   alert("blue is not your color get out of here");
}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<select onChange="window.top.location='lan.php?lan='+this.value;">
  <option>----</option>
  <option value="en">English</option>
  <option value="tr">Turkce</option>
</select>
```